# Removal of Cyberware, and Upgrade Essence costs

Tags: shadowrun, shadowrun-sr5

I am planning on my character being a troll mage who's corp born. In talks with my GM we have determined that in his world corp people get forced implants. So I am getting a free skilljack for better or for worse (as it screws with my magic).

But this leaves me with .7 essence to play with and gives me some possibilities in the future as I am completely broke at the moment. However, my characters drive is to remove my corp SIN and live a free life. Part of that might be to remove the device which they "gave" me.

In doing this would there be any essence recovery? I don't see anything in the rules. Also how do essence costs work with upgrading? Say I went from a standard rank 3 skilljack to a rank 6 would it cost a full .3 essence for me, giving me 5.4 essence? Or would it be unaffected? And how then would things work if it was an alpha ware or delta ware upgrade, since they have lower essence costs? This is going to probably not affect me with this character but I want to play a street Sam who I'm sure will need some chrome.

Thanks chummers!

Comment: I don't have the books with me right now but I see no reason to give back essence by removing implants. If I got my eyes chopped out and replaced by metal cameras and then I get them removed, I wouldn't regain my humanity..at least this is my opinion. I'll look in the books when I have them at hand.

Comment: Heh, you read my mind. I'm going through chargen in a game at the moment, and wanted to know whether upgrading to a higher rating of the same device costs the full essence loss or not.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that you should regain any essence, but the upgrading and or changing cyberware - because things do break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essence can be recovered, but it's very difficult. By default, removing cyberware leaves an Essence "hole", into which new cyberware can be installed. In 3rd Edition, Man & Machine handled several different ways for Essence costs to be modified via surgery and the like, and things like delta grade cyberware can decrease Essence costs, as can certain qualities, but it's not possible to regain Essence by itself.

Until 4th Edition's Augmentation came out, at least. It's technically not SR5, but it's part of 4e which is pretty similar, and better yet it's some of the parts that don't have mechanical changes between editions.

> Revitalization is a recent breakthrough that  repairs Essence loss derived from invasive implantation. Universal Omnitech is trying to keep the mechanism a secret, though geneticists have speculated that the effect is achieved by performing somekind
>   of “genetic feng shui.”
>   (Augmentation, p. 88)

So, in short, yes, it is possible to restore Essence loss after removing the implant, but it's difficult and expensive, not to mention time consuming (.1 Essence a month, and 20k per month, plus a hefty start-up fee). That said, it might be more readily available in 5th Edition.

In addition, I wouldn't be entirely unsurprised to see a metamagic for this at some point, especially since it's the sort of thing that I associate with Shadowrun's metaphysics (more from Adepts on the Earthdawn side) advancing to a certain point.

Comment: very good information thanks! What about upgrading or downgrading though? any idea on how going from a deltaware arm to a standard arm would effect your essence? Or are these situations covered in the essence hole you were referring to? I just want to be clear on it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the costs stack up, since you're installing into the Essence hole. That said, in one version they said "only augmentations of the same type (i.e. upgrades)", but in another they said "any augmentation", since multiple printings and such. I believe in 3rd Edition you could reinstall freely, and I'd do that in 5th edition personally.

As for the impacts of an arm, it depends on the modifications. Higher grade equals less essence cost, but a mere prosthetic replacement doesn't cost essence, so doesn't need to be high grade (though it would be more subtle).